# InfoPath 2010 Default Value Dropdown list using External Data Source (XML)

Tags: infopath

Is there a way to set a default value for a dropdown list using an XML data source? 
I don't mind manually entering it to match the dropdown field but I just can't seem to find a place for it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will have to use a rule to set the field's value.  You could do it on form load, but your requirements might dictate otherwise.